# How to include resources of a sub project in parent project?

Tags: java, web-applications, gradle, war

I have a multi-project gradle build containing 3 projects: `A`, `B` and `C`.

`A` and `B` depends on `C`.
`C` has a file `myconfig.xml` in its `resources` folder that I would like to include as resource in war generated for `A` and `B`.

```
A -- project type - WAR
  -- depends on - C
B -- project type - WAR
  -- depends on - C
C -- project type - JAVA
\_ src\main\resources
 \_ myconfig.xml
```

However, simply having C as a dependency for A & B doesnt seem to do that. The `myconfig.xml` file is *not* present in the war file's `WBE-INF\classes` folder.  It is indeed present in `C.jar` file but that is not where its needed.

How do i share the resources folder of `C` such that its in the war file of `A` and `B`?

Comment: Any sample project online to have a try?

Comment: Consider accessing the xml directly from `C.jar`, since it is in class path. You can open the resource as stream. Check this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20389255/reading-a-resource-file-from-within-jar

Comment: @AntonK. can you add this as an answer

Answer (score 3):

I am not sure how it works in gradle but in maven you could do it with maven-dependency-plugin:

```
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
            <artifactItems>
                <artifactItem>
                    <groupId>yourgroupid</groupId>
                    <artifactId>C</artifactId>
                    <version>${project.version}</version>
                    <type>jar</type>
                    <overWrite>true</overWrite>
                    <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/WEB-INF/classes</outputDirectory>
                    <includes>myconfig.xml</includes>
                </artifactItem>
            </artifactItems>
        </configuration>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <phase>compile</phase>
                <goals>
                    <goal>unpack</goal>
                </goals>
            </execution>
        </executions>
    </plugin>
```

There should be something similar in gradle too, just a pointer maybe.

Answer (score 2):

Consider accessing the xml directly from C.jar, since it is in class path. You can open the resource as stream. Check this post [Reading a resource file from within jar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20389255/reading-a-resource-file-from-within-jar)

Answer (score 1):

Can you explain how do you read myconfig.xml file? If you try using `getClass().getResourceAsStream("/myconfig.xml")` you will read it no matter it's in `WEB-INF/classes` folder or in a jar in classpath. Obviously, is better to put resources in jars into folders (e.g: `my-c-lib/myconfig.xml`) in order to avoid collisions.

Answer (score -1):

To use the resource of another project, we should import that project to our class path.

To import use,
<
classpathentry combineaccessrules="false" kind="src" path="/your project c path"/>

Add this entry in the classpath(.classpath file) project A and B

Comment: we are talking about a gradle project here. not sure which .classpath file you are talking about?

Comment: i am not familiar with gradle , but there must be a way to add dependency project at the time of compilation. hoping this will be use full:  https://java.net/downloads/satjug/Enter%20the%20Gradle.pdf